# About “tour d'horizon”

Tags: sens, expressions, étymologie

Has this phrase originated from an anecdote or story?

What does it mean precisely?

Can one use this phrase both in English and French?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it means is no problem; in connection with whatever matter that entails a lot of things under consideration it means "browsing of all those things in a certain way so as to verify a particular caracteristic of each or so as to find something in one or more of those things, etc.". To some instances;

- travel agencies: "Il fit un tour d'horizon des agences locales de voyage pour se trouver la meilleure offre sur des vacances en Chine."
- personal papers: "un tour d'horizon des papiers qu'il avait écrits récemment avait suffit à lui fournir la  réponse à la question qu'il se posait."
- fruit juice shelves: "Après avoir fait un tour d'horizon de l'étal des diverse sortes de jus de fruit elle acheta un litre de jus de myrtilles."

Il est plus difficile de fournir une explication de la raison du choix de mots pour cette expression; on peut cependant être à peu près sûr de ne pas se tromper en supposant que l'on doit ce choix particulier soit aux arts militaires, soit à ceux de la marine: dans ces deux domaines les champs d'action des êtres humains impliqués sont les grands espaces terrestres et marins, dans lesquels il importe de savoir se qui se passe de tout les côtés, ce que l'on ne peut faire qu'en tournant sur soi même en regardant au loin, c'est à dire vers l'horizon, d'où « un tour d'horizon ».

Surprisingly enough, this phrase can be used in [English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tour+d%27horizon&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctour%20d%27%20horizon%3B%2Cc0), unchanged: tour d'horizon. It means "a broad general survey", which is as in French. However it's bound to be only literary in English whereas in French you can use in speech.

Comment: J'avoue, merci de clarifier! Je venais tout juste d'investiguer: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5733/about-tour-de-force?rq=1 et je me demandais de quelle façon auprès elles étaient semblables.